# Correct program structure

Tags: c#, oop

My application is used for communication with electronic device. It reads some identification data (like device firmware version), some configuration data, and periodically data from sensors. Program is divided into three layers:

1. Data layer - simple structures describing how data are stored in device memory.
2. Business layer - classes used for communication with device. They contains structures from data layer and using them to store data when reading from and writing to device.
3. Presentation layer - user interface (WinForms); using businnes layer classes.

**Assume that:**

Data structures looks like:

```
public struct Configuration
{
 public int Option1;
 public int Option2;
}

public struct Visualization
{
 public int Temperature;
 public int Pressure;
}
```

Business layer classes wraps these structures and contains logic for communication:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<DataStructureType>
{
 protected DataStructureType dataStructure;
 public BaseEntity()
 {
  this.dataStructure = new DataStructureType();
 }
 /*
  device communication logic
 */
 public abstract bool GetAllData();
}

public class ConfigurationEntity : BaseEntity<Configuration>
{
 public override bool GetAllData()
 {
  //getting configuration data from device
 }
 public int Option1
 {
  get { return this.dataStructure.Option1; }
  set { this.dataStructure.Option1 = value; }
 }
 public int Option2;
 {
  get { return this.dataStructure.Option2 * 100; }
  set { this.dataStructure.Option1 = value / 100; }
 }
}

public class VisualizationEntity : BaseEntity<Visualization>
{
 public override bool GetAllData()
 {
  //getting visualization data from device
 }
 public int Temperature
 {
  get { return this.dataStructure.temperature; }
 }
 public float Pressure;
 {
  get { return Conversions.IntToPressure(this.dataStructure.pressure); }
 }
}
```

And Conversions class used to convert binary data:

```
public static class Conversions
{
 public static float IntToPressure(int parameter)
 {
  return PressureAlgorithmA(parameter);
 }
 private static float PressureAlgorithmA(int parameter)
 {
  //some algorithm (called A) to convert binary pressure to pressure in bars
 }
}
```

**Problem is** new firmware version, because application should handle both device versions(older and newer). New version has been updated with couple of new structures to read, new conversion algorithms, new configuration options. It looks like:

```
public struct Configuration
{
 /*
  old options are here
 */
 //and updated goes here:
 public int Option3;
 public int Option4;
}

public class ConfigurationEntity : BaseEntity<Configuration>
{
 /*
  old code is here
 */
 //and updated goes here
 public int Option3
 {
  get { return this.dataStructure.Option3; }
  set { this.dataStructure.Option3 = value; }
 }
 public int Option4;
 {
  get { return this.dataStructure.Option4 * 20; }
  set { this.dataStructure.Option4 = value / 20; }
 }
}
```

Also Conversions has beem changed:

```
public static class Conversions
{
 public static float IntToPressure(int parameter)
 {
  return PressureAlgorithmB(parameter);
 }
 private static float PressureAlgorithmB(int parameter)
 {
  //some algorithm (called B) to convert binary pressure to pressure in bars
 }
}
```

Now I have to check for device version every time I need to use new funcionality (when changing Option3 or Option4 from Configuration or when I need to use new data etities or which algorithm use when showing pressure to user).

My question is how can I do that with OOP practicies? What is correct way to do this in C#?

I was thinking about factory pattern, but what with new options in Configuration, or with new data entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to maintain the same architecture for different versions of external component (device in your case) the plug-in based architecture can help you.

For example, you can:

Every `BusinessLayer` class should implement `IPluginInterface` (say), as this the layer where actuall communication with device should happen.

There should be some `Communicator` class, who reads device version information and picks from collection of available `BusinessLayers`, that one which is aable to manage required version.

Just to give you an idea.

Comment: I don't know if I understand it correctly, but your solution solves part of my problem (different data structures versions). But what with new busiiness layer classes using structures from new version? And how maintain new funconalities in old business layer classes

Comment: In my solution you have a collection of BusinessLayers and Communicator first reads a version info from device and after choose from the collection of BusinessLayers appropriate one

Comment: You mean I have to implement two versions of each BusinessLayer class (one for each device version)?

Comment: Yes, cause there where you have different implamentation, cause the device can be different, or the same but with different version.

Comment: Have you an idea how I can use BusinessLayer classes in Presentationlayer without checking for device version each time i need to use them?

Comment: Well, on program startup you can check for device version and save that infromation in some global variable. So check the version on every start-up, cause, I immagine, after you close an application you can change connected device.

Comment: I mean that how to avoid version checking (not reading from device) each time I nedd to use new functionality. Because I imagine that I have two classes for Configuration (ConfigurationVer1, ConfigurationVer2) and two instances of these classes: (configurationVer1, configurationVer2). When I have to set Option4 (from configuration2) I need to check: if (deviceVersion == 2) and then set value. How to avoid these situations?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid that

Comment: I'm just seeking solution similar to factory, where I have to only replace used object depending on device version. But when I'm thinking more about that I conclude that this can not be done.

Comment: Well you are asking about *exactly* what I'm talking about. You have a collection of BLayers, and "someone" should query device for version and pick the right BLayer. That "someone" could be Communicator, Factory class, whatever you want...

Comment: Ok, but as you can see from code in my post, new version of BLayer classes, for example ConfigurationE, are not the same, because in new class there are new properties/methods. I can't make one abstract class for these two versions of ConfigurationE.

Comment: I'm ready to accept your answer, but I need just one more advice. I can make abstract ConfigurationEntity as base class for Configuration, then make two implementations of Configuration(V1 and V2) but what with additional methods/properties in V2? Should I implement them as interface? Something like `IV82Configuration { Option3 {get;set;} Option4 {get;set;}`?

Comment: @adams: there must be, for sure, somewhere a place when you distinguish *real* type from the it's abstraction, like for example to be able to access to some members that *are not* present inside abstract class/interface. I would suggest to make abstraction *as much as it possible* and stop on some reasonable level of your architecture. Begiining from that level there should be (say) `if(type is ConfigV1) Dosomehitng(); else if(type id ConfigV2)SomethigElse;` It's not possible to write 100% abstract programs.